# I am unable to install packages for python2 specifically, pip and pip3 point to the same version

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

**Context:** Running an exploit vs a vulnerable VM as a part of my OSCP studies. I know this VM is vulnerable to this exploit because I ran the exploit inside MSF(pentesting framework) and it worked, but doing it manually I am having dependency issues.

**Setup:** I am on kali, latest quarterly release

**Exploit:** https://github.com/andyacer/ms08_067

[Pip versions output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km6xl.png)

[Trying to install dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIItt.png)

Keep in mind on kali "python" points to python2.7.18, and python3 points to python3.xwhatever because of backwards compatibility (funny huh) because tons of exploits are written in python2

the script uses `#!/usr/bin/env python` thus points to python2.7.18

I have already tried various solutions from various SO threads as well as articles on google.

Comment: What do you get for `pip2 --version`? `pip2` should point to the python2 installation. If not, these are usually symlinks and you can create a symlink to the correct pip manually.

Comment: I am completely unable to install pip2. Its like it doesnt exist. I didnt manage to find a single command on google that would lead to installing pip2. Unironically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Kali forums:
https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?48570-New-Kali-build-cannot-install-pip-for-python2-7

```
    curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
    python get-pip.py
```

Note that I had to modify the link to pip2.7 as the old link in the forum pointed to 3.6

That should get you going.

Comment: Weird thing is I ran the get-pip.py script yesterday and it errored out. but downloading it from the link u provided it installed and seems its gonna work now. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check under `/usr/local/lib` that you have some version of python2 installed?

You should also be able to run `python2 -V` to verify that you do have python2 installed.

To install pip for python2, download `get-pip.py` from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and then run this command:

```
sudo python2 get-pip.py
```

This should create a `pip2` symlink on your system. It might replace the existing `pip` symlink too. Either way, it should solve your issue.

Comment: Yeah, worked fine. I wasnt able to find pip2 installation package. Fingers crossed I will be able to run the exploit now.